# 403 Forbidden : You don't have permission to access this resource

Tags: ruby, apache2

I need to create a site but when i start apache2 services i don't have permission.
My site contains ruby and apache, i need ruby app on my apache2

That my apache2 config.

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/Pass>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

/Pass is my folder with my ruby app.

Thanks for you help !

Comment: Do you have `passenger` installed? https://www.phusionpassenger.com/

Comment: Yes, i have, rails,ruby,passenger,apache2, my app etc

Comment: https://www.phusionpassenger.com/docs/tutorials/deploy_to_production/installations/oss/ownserver/ruby/apache/ ... did you look at the Passenger for Apache documentation?

Comment: I does the instructions to the site for my app and it's doesn't work

Comment: can you post in the examples of your code that incorporate the passenger config?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry i'm not on my linux last time... i does install_passenger_apache2 and i have this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NLzvr.png)

Comment: it would be better to have edited your question, rather than add an answer.  You will need to look at the log files generated in your apache.  hopefully your "passenger.log" is set up as a possible output, but they might be in the Apache logs